# Spring web XML not respecting XmlRootElement in Java11

Tags: java, xml, java-11

I migre my app to JDK11 (from JDK 8) so I up to `springboot` `2.2.4.RELEASE` and I add `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml`

**my model:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "dataModel")
public class DataModel {
    ...
}
```

**my controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{model}/columns", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<DataModel> getColumnsModel(@PathVariable String model) {
    LOGGER.info("getColumnsModel : model[{}]", model);
    DataModel dataModel = modelService.getColumns(model);
    return Optional.ofNullable(dataModel).map(result -> new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK)).orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT));
}
```

**client:**

```
curl -s --header "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8084/api/foo/columns
```

**JDK8:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><dataModel><columns>author</columns><columns>zip</columns><columns>city</columns><columns>element</columns><columns>element2</columns><columns>date</columns><columns>title</columns></dataModel>
```

**JDK11:**

```
<DataModel><columns><columns>author</columns><columns>zip</columns><columns>city</columns><columns>element</columns><columns>element2</columns><columns>date</columns><columns>title</columns></columns></DataModel>
```

**new result is strang:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><dataModel>` => `<DataModel>`

`<dataModel><columns>author</columns>...</dataModel>` => `<DataModel><columns><columns>author</columns>...</columns></DataModel>`

I try add this dependencies but do not resolve:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: No it isn't. JDK11 doesn't have JAXB included, and it is now using its own XML marshalling instead of JAXB. Include JAXB in your dependencies to make it work again. Instead of blindly upgrading a JDK version you might first want to read the release notes/changes that have happend in a release!

Comment: I do not have an error (in my logs) but my xml result is wrong `<DataModel><columns><columns>author</columns>...</columns></DataModel>`

Comment: @M.Deinum, `jaxb-api`, `jaxb-core`, `jaxb-impl` are all ready in my project.

Comment: Also you should remove the jackson xml dependency as that will now be used instead of jaxb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```